# Calling ActionScript from Python. Is that possible?

Tags: python, flash, actionscript-3

If swf file is embedded in html it is easy to call ActionScript methods via ExternalInterface using JavaScript.
Now I want to use the swf file outside of a browser and still be able to access its methods, but now I want to use Python to call ActionScript. Is it possible?
There is so little information about it in the Internet.
Probably I can use AMF (pyAmf) for this, can I?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the swf in such a manner outside the browser investigate AIR or localconnection.

[Edit] You can use Python to listen for ExternalInterface events. osflash.org has something you could look into, albeit a little outdate:

http://osflash.org/ext_howto

or some example Python:

```
def ExternalCall(self,evt):
    print "ExternalCall", evt.request
    ret = "<object><property><string>Sample data</string></property></object>"
    self.movie.SetReturnValue(ret)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this? I am totally new to AcrionScript/Flash/AIR etc. What I need is to build some kind of a wrapper around existing flash application (swf file). The application exposes some API through ExternalInterface. And I need to be able to access that API outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your swf can listen for connections with [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html), acting like a server. [ByteArray.readObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readObject%28%29) can read object in AMF format from message bytes, so you can encode method name and arguments in object.

Comment: That probably could be a solution if I had access to application's source code. But I have only a published version of the application. So it seems that the only choice that I have is to access it via ExternalIntrface. But I am lost on how to do it outside of the browser.

Comment: You should mention in your question your specific situation. You asked if Python can communicate with AS3 but your question is more specific than that; can Python use the ExternalInterface callbacks that have already been established?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. So, your comment most accurately describes what I need to achieve.

Comment: If swf is playing in standalone player, there is no ExternalInterface at all. The link (http://osflash.org/ext_howto) that Zophiel found, talks about ActiveX Flash objects, ie embedded into some program. So you need to look how to do this, then establish ExternalInterface links.